# propiedades de classe de un archivo externo

Tags: php, clase, atributos

es posible hacer esto de alguna manera en php?

Archivo principal

```
<?php
    class Class_APP{
        require_once 'propiedades.php';
        public function __construct() {

        }
    }
?>
```

archivo externo propiedades.php

```
<?php
    protected $CONTENTMANAGER;
    protected $MENUMANAGER;
    protected $FORMMANAGER;
    protected $PROCESSMANAGER;
    protected $MODALSMANAGER;
    protected $DBMANAGER;
?>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde definirías o dónde usarías `CONTENTMANAGER`  y demás familiares?

Comment: Estoy pensando usarlo en una clase que sea Extendiada de APP ejemplo: `class Class_MAIN extends Class_APP { #contenido }`

Comment: la idea es usar Class APP como un hub para hacer el require_once de todas las clases, cuales sea. y al mismo tiempo definir las propiedades pero para cuestiones de mantenimiento queria saber si es posible manejar en un archivo externo estas propiedades que luego seran heredadas con extends Class_APP

Comment: La clase que extienda de `Class_APP` heredará sus propiedades y métodos, así que los puedes tener directamente en la clase... no le veo sentido a querer hacerlo con un requiere... Tal y como lo tienes no funcionará, porque cuando creas una instancia de la clase el método que se ejecuta es el constructor y tendrás este error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'require_once' (T_REQUIRE_ONCE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)`

Comment: lo se... por eso pregunto si hay alguna manera de hacerlo...

Comment: La manera de hacerlo es poniendo las propiedades en la clase misma... ese es el sentido de la POO. Si los que crearon la POO se enteran de lo que quieres hacer creo que pedirían algunos años de prisión para ti por este intento suicida. Ten en cuenta que una clase representa una **entidad** completa de un programa o aplicación. Si quieres heredar, o usar de nuevo... para eso existe la herencia, el poliformismo y demás familiares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deseas hacer marcaria error pero dado que en php no ncesitas definir una variable antes de usarla podrias hacer:

```
<?php
//propiedades.php
$this->CONTENTMANAGER = null;
$this->MENUMANAGER = null;
$this->FORMMANAGER = null;
$this->PROCESSMANAGER = null;
$this->MODALSMANAGER = null;
$this->DBMANAGER = null;
```

Archivo de tu clase:

```
class Class_APP{



      public function __construct() {
        include ('propiedades.php');
      }
  }
```

y al hacer un `var_dump(new Class_APP());` el resultado seria:

```
object(Class_APP)#1 (6) {
  ["CONTENTMANAGER"]=>
  NULL
  ["MENUMANAGER"]=>
  NULL
  ["FORMMANAGER"]=>
  NULL
  ["PROCESSMANAGER"]=>
  NULL
  ["MODALSMANAGER"]=>
  NULL
  ["DBMANAGER"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Sin embargo dado que estas propiedades se están definiendo dinamicante la clase no tiene las propiedades y no podría heredarlas.

Comment: gracias amigo, pero de alguna manera ya corregi esto creando una propiedad y rellenandola de datos https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/112021/46896